# Rank based on Sequence of dates in Spotfire

Tags: spotfire

I am new to Spotfire and would appreciate any help on this. 
Here is a sample data i am working on...

```
Well_ID    Date    Oil_Rate
1       8/30/17     614.62
1       8/31/17     614.62
1       9/01/17     873.07
1       9/02/17     873.07
```

And I need Something like below

```
Well_ID   Date     Oil_Rate    Rank
1       8/30/17     614.62     1
1       8/31/17     614.62     2
1       9/01/17     873.07     1
1       9/02/17     873.07     2
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Are you aware that there is a `rank` function in Spotfire?

Answer (score 3):

This simple Rank function should suffice:
`Rank([Date],Month([Date]),[Well_ID])`

[image]

Ranks the Dates by their month and by Well_ID. other columns can be added as well to Rank over.

Comment: @user9894150 if this solution worked please consider accepting it as an answer to your original question :)